# Internet Explorer HTML Markup Is Not Updated Immediately

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer

I am developing a website for IE 11. It's a WordPress website with custom theme. Whenever I update HTML markup or JS script in PHP file, for example header.php, and upload it to server, and then visit the website in IE, it doesn't contain the newly added markup while in Chrome it contains the markup perfectly. I tried to hard refresh it ( ctrl + f5 ), but it still didn't work.

I've also deleted IE cache and data, but it couldn't work either. I have to wait several minutes to hours before the markup is updated in IE. Is this normal behavior in IE? Is there any way so I can see the markup changes immediately like in Chrome and Firefox?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried no-cache headers?

Comment: Does your wordpress use caching plugins? Remember to flush those as well.

Comment: @SimonaB, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @BasvanStein, Yes. I forgot to flush the caching plugin. It's just strange that IE doesn't update the markup immediately while other browsers do. Thanks!

Comment: Added it as answer so you can accept it. Most cache plugins show the real page when users are logged in, that might be the difference of the two browsers in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using caching plugins in wordpress it is also necessary to flush the cache there. It might be that you were loggedin in chrome and therefor the non-cached version was shown while in IE the cached version was served.